# Has anyone successfully set up their email settings on EngineYard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, google-apps

I am attempting to add email capabilities to my app (forgotten password, notifications, etc.) and I am using EngineYard for hosting. I have successfully configured email in my test environment but upon uploading to EY it seems to error out in Production. I don't pay for their support and the [only resource is a bit vague](https://community.engineyard.com/faqs/questions/ssmtp) (or beyond me).

I am curious to know if there is any specific file additions, server set up etc. that is needed when using email on EY. I am using Google apps so I thought it would be as easy as adding the same code block for test in production but doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? How far have you got following the instructions in that page you linked to?

Comment: Have you tried asking on their community forums? Most of the time they reply.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this google-apps instead of google-app-engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my config for Google apps, in .../config/environments/production.rb:

```
require 'tlsmail' 
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port => 587,
  :tls => true,
  :domain => 'example.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "sender@example.com",
  :password => 'tr1ckypwd!'
}
```

Note, for the security minded out there, I actually keep the password in a separate file and have code to patch it into the settings on launch, but I figured that would distract from the meat of the response.

Hope that helps.